# Is there any sure way to know that siri is launched while my app is running?

Tags: ios, objective-c, siri

Suppose, while the user is using the app he long taps the home button and siri opens up. Is there any way to know this through some event or notification or delegate methods?

I want to know if siri is launched while my app is running. Is there any sure way to know?

Comment: Can you please provide some more info, what is exact case scenario you want to check. (So, you left Cricket and started coding)

Comment: Suppose, while the user is using the app he long taps the home button and siri opens up. Is there any way to know this through some event or notification or delegate methods? (Nobody wants to pay me anymore for playing cricket ;) )

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.1 - iOS 12.0.0

So far there is only *work-around solution* to detect whether Siri is running or not for my use-case.

**Caution**: Please test it carefully in your project to double check (*since we are relying on AVAudioSession which is not related with Siri Kit*)

```
func hasSiri() -> Bool {
    let audioSession = AVAudioSession.sharedInstance()
    return audioSession.inputDataSource == nil ||
        audioSession.inputDataSources == nil ||
        audioSession.inputDataSources?.isEmpty == true
}
```

Comment: I figure out the inputDataSource is also empty when calling with some app, facetime, line, meet, etc. And I still dont not have the other way to get siri status.

Answer (score -1):

Based on your requirements there is no method will notify app that Siri open and close notification.

But yes if you want to catch that there are some method where you will get notify while below action accure

1. Phone call received.
2. Whatsapp or any other video call received.
3. Siri open while long press on home button.

in above all scenario app will notify in below method and based on that you can handle that event over there.

**==>** `applicationWillResignActive`

```
func applicationWillResignActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
```

> - Sent when the application is about to move from active to inactive state. This can occur for certain types of temporary interruptions
>     (such as an incoming phone call or SMS message) or when the user quits
>     the application and it begins the transition to the background state.
> - Use this method to pause ongoing tasks, disable timers, and invalidate graphics rendering callbacks. Games should use this method
>     to pause the game.

**==>** `applicationWillEnterForeground` & `applicationDidBecomeActive` (while user come back on your app from background

```
func applicationWillEnterForeground(_ application: UIApplication) {

}
```

> - Called as part of the transition from the background to the active
>     state; here you can undo many of the changes made on entering the
>     background.

```
    func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

    }
```

> - Restart any tasks that were paused (or not yet started) while the application was inactive. If the application was previously in the
>     background, optionally refresh the user interface.

other than above methods you can not get any notification where you will handle Siri open from your app.

Hope this will help to understand app delegate flow of notification.